# SQL Server 2012 LocalDB: how to retrieve path to Binn?

Tags: sql-server, smo

I use SMO objects in my c# app to get it. I.e. I use
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.Information class and use RootDirectory and MasterDBPath. It works ok. But for LocalDB there no tehse properties.
I neetd it to have a possibility to install extended stored procedires.

How to get it for LocalDB?

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB binaries are always installed into `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn`. Note that binaries in this folder are shared between all LocalDB instances from all users. Be careful mocking with it :-)